# Plural of 'hereafter'

Tags: grammatical-number

On Wiktionary we read that 'hereafter' has as plural 'hereafters', but OALD says that this plural form doesn't exist. Which is wrong: Wiktionary or OALD?

Comment: @Jasper Loy - Hmm... 'simply' seems excessively simplicistic in this case, but I hope in eventual answers to clarify my question.

Comment: With no context whatsoever but the question 'Which is wrong, Wiktionary or X?', the almost always correct answer would be 'not Wiktionary'. In this case however, sure, 'the hereafter', like 'the future' is not a mass noun (one only normally thinks of there only being one of them), so one might in some scifi novel refer to 'one of many hereafters'. Dictionaries aren't always consistently comprehensive spelling out every possible legally suffixed version.

Comment: @JasperLoy: I agree with you. That said, I think I know where his doubt comes from. If you go to [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/) and type in _hats_ it will return the entry for _hat_.  Same thing happens for _driveways_, _highways_, _angels_, _demons_, _emus_, _roosters_, and _hens_.  But, when you search for _hereafters_, instead of sending you to the entry for _hereafter_, it goes to a page with reads: **Sorry, no search result for hereafters.**  Curious indeed.

Comment: @J.R. - yes, you have perfectly understood where my doubt comes from.

Comment: @AngloSaxon: I think you might have more success asking questions here if you construct them more carefully. There's a chance – perhaps – had you presented your original question more like my comment, instead of leaving it to the rest of the community to figure out this vital information, others would not have been so quick to close it. I'll point to [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65292/) as a good example where the O.P. did a great job of framing a question so that the rest of the community could think and answer, instead of performing all the preliminary research.

Answer (score 3):

From the Oxford English Dictionary, under the noun entry for *hereafter*:

> 1689   W. Sherlock Pract. Disc. Death (1731) iii. §6. 143   *The
>   Reason‥will serve for all **hereafters**, but will never serve for any
>   Time present*.

Evidently, it's a word.  Not a widely used word, mind you, but a word nonetheless.

Also, from a Google Book search (under *The Complete Works of Thomas Brooks, Volume 4*):

[image]